# Cordova plugin File always returns null value

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have a malfunction of the Cordova File plugin.
This is a service that I have created in order to manage document downloads in my app.

The cause of the problem is that this.file.externalRootDirectory always returns a null value. I don't know what the cause can be. I appreciate your help.
Here I leave my function.

```
import { FileOpener } from '@ionic-native/file-opener/ngx';
import { File } from "@ionic-native/file/ngx";

  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private notificationService: NotificationService,
    private fileOpener: FileOpener,
    private file: File
  ) {
  }

  async downloadFile(base64String: string, extension: string, fileName: string) {
    const dt = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).split('-').join('').split(':').join('');
    fileName = `${fileName}-${dt}.${extension}`;
    const blob = this.b64toBlob(base64String, this.getMimeTypeFromExt(extension));
    if (this.platform.is('android')) {
      const path = `${this.file.externalRootDirectory + '/Download/'}`;
      this.file.writeFile(
        path,
        fileName,
        blob
      )
      .then(() => {
        this.fileOpener.open(`${path}${fileName}`, this.getMimeTypeFromExt(extension)).then( () => {
        }).catch((error) => {
          this.notificationService.error(MSG.OPENING_DOCUMENT_ERROR);
        });
      }).catch((error) => {
        this.notificationService.error(MSG.DOWNLOADED_DOCUMENT_ERROR);
      });
    } else {
      const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      if ( extension === 'pdf' ) {
        const newWindow = window.open();
        newWindow.location.href = fileURL;
      } else {
        const link = document.createElement("a");
        link.href = fileURL;
        link.download = fileName
        link.click();
      }
    }
  }
```

PS: A few days ago it was working fine for me, but it has started to work badly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the `extra filesystems`

```
<preference name="iosExtraFilesystems" value="library,library-nosync,documents,documents-nosync,cache,bundle,root" />
<preference name="AndroidExtraFilesystems" value="files,files-external,documents,sdcard,cache,cache-external,assets,root" />
```

By default, the above should be already set, unless if you have overwritten in.

You can see more details from [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file#configuring-the-plugin-optional)